# ASP.NET Core dual routes for web and api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is for an ASP.NET Core application. A json Web API needs to be added alongside a normal website.

So in `program.cs`, a second route was added:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    pattern{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//2nd route for web api
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", 
    pattern: "{controller=WebApi}/{Action}/{country?}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

The Web API `WebApicontroller` was written, and the class starts as below  - noting the `[` brackets `]` syntax.

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 
namespace myprogram.Controllers
{
    // [System.Web.Http.Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}")]  
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}")]
    public class WebApiController : ApiController
    {
        // http://localhost:53912/webapi/Test
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("Test")]
        public string Test()
        return "Tested"; 
    }
}
```

Opening a page alike `http://localhost:53912/webapi/test` doesn't work.
What am I missing? I must be overlooking something here.

Comment: Hi, 1. why you mix asp.net(System.Web.Http) with asp.net core(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components)? 2. Although mix with them, you can also hit the endpoint. 3. What do you mean for `doesn't work`? What's the error message or status code?

Comment: @Peter your problem is you are enforcing the `{id}` in your `WebApiController`'s `Route`. To prove, try `http://localhost:53912/webapi/test/1` (appended `/1`) and it will work.
So, you could make it optional: `{id?}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the second option from your config

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

and make a controller route id optional, since your test for example doesn't have id parameter

```
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]
    public class WebApiController : ApiController
```

or you can add the route to the action directly

```
 [Route("~/webapi/test")]
 public string Test()
```

Comment: its optionsal in de route, but added it in the controller as well, its not solving

Comment: @Peter This controller route was tested and working properly at my machine. But if you don't want it for some reason , you can just add action route

Comment: I generated a small testapi, it used the syntax you mentioned.
Restarted VS2022, origrinal prj added a new controller, same syntax but in new controller file worked.
I now doubt , maybe i miss clicked on the empty api controller, program.cs didnt change.